# When BasicTextField focused, the layout rise incorrectly

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I click on the input field, the input field is partially blocked by the soft keyboard, rather than completely displayed on the soft keyboard.

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun ChatBottomBar() {
    var editingText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    BasicTextField(
        value = editingText,
        onValueChange = { editingText = it },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(4.dp, 8.dp)
            .height(40.dp)
            .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.small)
            .background(WeTheme.colors.textFieldBackground)
            .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 10.dp, end = 8.dp),
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(WeTheme.colors.iconCurrent)
    )
}
```

And here is screenshot, it run on my device.

[The soft keyboard cannot rise correctly!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZWg7.png)

By the way, when you click the BasicTextField(includes TextField and OutLinedTextField) for the first time, it can not rise at all, there is a screenshot below.

[the soft keyboard rise only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHWAh.png)

Then I achieve this by TextField, it looks better but still meet these problems, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in AndroidManifest to your coresponding activity.
Ex:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.myActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" //for my project
        android:label="mylabel"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
         android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/myTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, but it dosen's work 